# VBA Export to text file. Need to use a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export a range of rows that falls between 2 entries in the B column that are manually inputted using a prompt.  For example a prompt would ask me for the first and 2nd search words and I would enter cat and then dog.  B5 has the word cat and B50 has the word dog. I want to capture rows 6 to 49 and then pass it through what is below and have the output sent to a text file.

`Sub ExportColumnsABToText()`

```
Dim oStream As Object
Dim sTextPath As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim sText2 As String
Dim sLine As String
Dim sType As String
Dim rIndex As Long, cIndex As Long

sTextPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("export.txt", "Text Files, *.txt")
If sTextPath = False Then Exit Sub

sText = ""

For rIndex = 4 To 700
    sLine = ""
    sType = Sheets![worksheet1].Cells(rIndex, 8).Text

            If sType = "A" Or sType = "CNAME" Then
        For cIndex = 1 To 2
            If cIndex > 1 Then
                sLine = sLine & vbTab
            End If
                sLine = sLine & Sheets![worksheet1].Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Text
        Next cIndex
        If Not Len(Trim(Replace(sLine, vbTab, ""))) = 0 Then
            If rIndex > 4 Then
                sText = sText & IIf(sText = "", "", vbNewLine) & sLine
            End If
        End If
    End If
    ' End If

Next rIndex


Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With oStream
  .Type = 2
  .Charset = "UTF-8"
  .Open
  .WriteText sText
  .SaveToFile sTextPath, 2
  .Close
End With

Set oStream = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
Sub ExportColumnsABToText()


    Dim rngFind As Range, rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range, rngPrint As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Criteria1, Criteria2
    Dim sTextPath

    sTextPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("export.txt", "Text Files, *.txt")
    If sTextPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Set rngFind = Columns("B")

    Criteria1 = InputBox("Enter first criteria")
    Criteria2 = InputBox("Enter Second criteria")

    If Criteria1 = "" Or Criteria2 = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter both criteria"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rngStart = rngFind.Find(What:=Criteria1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set rngEnd = rngFind.Find(What:=Criteria2, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If rngStart Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Criteria1 not found"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rngEnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Criteria2 not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim str_text As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    FileNum = FreeFile

    For i = (rngStart.Row + 1) To (rngEnd.Row - 1)
        For j = 1 To 26
            str_text = str_text & " " & Cells(i, j)
        Next

        Open sTextPath For Append As #FileNum    ' creates the file if it doesn't exist
        Print #FileNum, str_text    ' write information at the end of the text file
        Close #FileNum
        str_text = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh,  How would I incorporate your code into the code provided above?  Is there a way to have your code not include the search words and the entire rows? - Thanks

Comment: @Badicus Copy the code to a new excel file and play around to see if it meets your requirement. If not let me know what changes you need.

Comment: Santosh,  The code you provided mostly does what I would like.  The changes would be to use the entire row (columns A-Z for example) and to not include the search words but what is between the search words.

Comment: Santosh,  That code does exactly what I am looking for on the first part Thank you very much.  I just have to figure out how to pass it to my original code and have it create the file afterwards.